# Calculate how large to make a collection of rectangles so they fill as much space within a larger box as possible

Tags: math, text, geometry, area

I very well could come up with a solution to this in the next couple of hours, in which case I'll post the answer as well, but I thought this was a fun enough problem that some of you would enjoy it.

Given a number n, a rectangle with bottom side length r and left side length (r * 0.6), and a bounding box with dimensions l x w. Solve for r so that n rectangles fill as much of the bounding box as possible. Rectangles can not be rotated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: It's math yes, but this is the exact same as asking "how big should I make a font to fill a box", I think it's very relevant to programming, even if abstracted.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up running with.

```
w * h = area

area = n * (x * (0.612 * x))

area / n = 0.612 * x^2

area / (0.612 * n) = x^2

x = Math.sqrt(area / (0.612 * n))
```